# Linq query with delegate does not update a variable

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

Short question about the code below.
Why does it always display 0?

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>() { "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes"};
int hitCount = 0;
strList.Select(i =>
{
    if(i.Equals("Yes"))
    {
        hitCount++;
    }
    return i;           
});
Console.WriteLine(hitCount); // always returns 0.
Console.Read();
```

Comment: You only construct the query, but never run it.

Comment: Because of the delayed execution, make a ToList() after the select and it should increase the hitcount ;)

Comment: [`.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) is a better way to count the elements matching a predicate -- no delayed execution worries or extra lists.

Comment: Did you make any attempt to debug this? Did you set a breakpoint on the `hitCount++` statement, to see if it ever got executed? Did you stop to think why it might _not_ get executed? Your question provides no evidence of any attempt to solve your problem; you simply ask why the output is what it is.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't use LINQ functions in ways that cause side effects (= change state outside the function boundary. Here: increment `hitCount`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically in your case query is not running, its just a simple `Select` and `retrun`, either you have to add `ToList()` at the end of query  to run query actually or you can do something else to run items having value `Yes`. Using `Count` is much faster in this case.

```
int hitcount = strList.Count(p => p == "Yes");
```

Or use can use `Where` clause and `Count`

```
hitcount = strList.Where(p => p == "Yes").Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Select statement only creates the query, if you call:

```
result.ToList();
```

it will force enumeration of the query, and the counter will be updated.